# Woocommerce: Change Font Size for Subcategory

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, font-size

I added a subcategory in Woocommerce and now I want to display the subcategory in bold and also make the font size bigger, so that it looks like a subcategory and not like one of the product categories.
Here is where I want to change it: https://ecsense.com/ec-sense-products/
(I want to change it for "Single Gas Modules" and "Dual Gas Modules")

Until now I looked through the CSS code which was made by someone else, but I could not find any code for Categories. The Main Categories are already displayed in bold and big by woocommerce.
So I would need a whole new section for Product Categories in my CSS. If anyone knows how to add a CSS code, please tell me.

Comment: Sophie, you need to learn to use your _Web Inspector_ - it will help you tremendously. Right-click on the element you want to inspect and select `Inspect` (in Firefox on Windows, but any browser on any operating system is similar). From there you will be able to see where the element sits in the document structure, whether the element has any pseudo-elements attached or if it's scrollable or if it has any events attached etc. In this instance, you will be able to see where the CSS styles are that apply to the element. You will be able to add your new CSS rule there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS Code:

```
#filter-bar .bapf_body >ul >li:nth-child(2)>ul >li> label {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check this CSS code

```
.bapf_body ul li > ul li > ul li > label {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

output is like : http://prntscr.com/1gzqcci